# Encrypt email address using java

Tags: java

I want to encrypt email address in java. The output of the email address also should be a valid email address.

Are there any apis for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java.crypto package exposes few classes for the same. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) out.
On generating valid email:

- Either you encrypt the full email address and then append `@encrypted.co` to the encrypted text
- Or, just encrypt email alias (text before `@`) and then use same domain suffix

It all depends on your usecase

Comment: So will test@gmail.com and test@yahoo.com will produce different valid email?

Comment: 1st approach will but 2nd will not.

Comment: Suppose "test@yahoo.com" encrption can create some invalid texts in between? So appending with "@encrypted.co" can make in an invalid email id?